# Updating table data via PHP/MySql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I was trying to create a page to create or update data in a table of my db.

If I recall the link by entering new data (in my case a new player), the data is correctly inserted into the table. Instead if I go to recall the link with data already present, to update the table, I always receive the echo "Error Update", and the first UPDATE if is never executed.

Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong?

```
<?php
include "coredb.php";

if (isset($_GET["player"]) && isset($_GET["score"]))
{
    //Check id player is already present in leaderboard database
    if ($query = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT Player FROM leaderboard WHERE Player = ?'))
    {
        $query->bind_param("s", $_GET["player"]);
        $query->execute();
        $query->fetch();
        // If player already present in leaderboard (result > 0)
        if ($query->num_rows > 0)
        {
            // Update existing database record
            if ($query = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE leaderboard SET Score = ? WHERE Player = ?')) {
                $query->bind_param("i", $_GET["score"]);
                $query->execute();
                echo "Existing player record updated!";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Error Update";
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            // Create new record in database
            if ($query = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO leaderboard (Player, Score) VALUES (?, ?)'))
            {
                $query->bind_param("si", $_GET["player"], $_GET["score"]);
                $query->execute();
                echo "New player record create!";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Error Create";
            } 
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Error database";
}

// Connection close
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: You're not binding the value for "Player" in your update query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please always use PDO or Prepared MySQLI to avoid SQL injections.
Someone could drop your tables or do other dangerous things that will ruin your data.

Also make sure you use a POST request to send sensitive information to your server.
If you use GET, everyone will be able to see the data you are transporting.

Refer to this example:

```
<?php

$dbhost     = 'localhost';
$dbname     = 'pdo';
$dbusername = 'root';
$dbpassword = '845625';

if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    //Select player
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT player FROM leaderboard WHERE player = :player");
    $stmt->execute([
        'player' => $_POST['player']
    ]);
    $result = $stmt->fetchColumn();

    if (!$result) {

        //Insert data
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `leaderboard` (player, score) VALUES (:player, :score)');

        $stmt->execute([
            'player' => $_POST['player'],
            'score' => $_POST['score']
        ]);

        echo 'New data inserted';

    } else {

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE `leaderboard` SET score = :score WHERE player = :player');
        $stmt->execute([
            'score' => $_POST['score'],
            'player' => $_POST['player']
        ]);

        echo 'Existing data updated: ' . $stmt->rowCount() . ' rows.';

    }

}   

?>

<form method="POST" action="">
   <input type="text" name="player">
   <input type="text" name="score">
   <button type="submit" name="submit">
      Submit data
   </button>
</form>
```